# Splitting string value in given column (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe with many rows like this:

| ID | Variable |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1_1 - Red |
| 2 | A1_2 - Blue |
| 3 | A1_3 - Yellow |

I'm trying to iterate over all rows so that all the 2nd column's values change to just "A1". The code I've come up with is:

```
for row in df.iterrows():

  current_response_id=row[1][0]

  columncount=0

  for columncount in range(2):

    variable=row[1][1];

    row[1][1]=variable.split("_")[0].split(" -")[0]

    variable=row[1][1];
```

However, this isn't achieving the desired result. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["Variable"] = df["Variable"].str.split("_").str[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Variable
0   1       A1
1   2       A1
2   3       A1
```

Comment: That worked wonders! Thanks! However, I still don't understand why my initial code didn't.